# why does the MomentOfInertia behave differently for ConvexHullMesh and ConvexHullRegion

Tags: functions, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a list of points of a convex polyhedron for which I need to compute the eigenvectors of the Moment of Inertia matrix. But, it seems like the built-in `MomentOfInertia` behave very differently for `ConvexHullMesh` and `ConvexHullRegion`

```
pts3 = {{0.9000000000000000222`8., 0.4500000000000000111`8., 0.5`8.}, {0.6750000000000000444`8., 0.8397114317029974462`8., 0.5`8.}, {0.2250000000000000056`8., 0.8397114317029974462`8., 0.5`8.}, {0, 0.4500000000000000111`8., 0.5`8.}, {0.2250000000000000056`8., 0.060288568297002243`8., 0.5`8.}, {0.6750000000000000444`8., 0.060288568297002243`8., 0.5`8.}, {0.9000000000000000222`8., 0.4500000000000000111`8., 0.1`8.}, {0.6750000000000000444`8., 0.060288568297002243`8., 0.1`8.}, {0.2250000000000000056`8., 0.060288568297002243`8., 0.1`8.}, {0, 0.4500000000000000111`8.,0.1`8.}, {0.2250000000000000056`8., 0.8397114317029974462`8., 0.1`8.}, {0.6750000000000000444`8., 0.8397114317029974462`8., 0.1`8.}};

(*plotting function*)
plt[region_, eigvec_, cent_] := Show[region,Graphics3D[{{Green, Thick, InfiniteLine[cent, #] &/@ eigvec}, 
{Opacity[0.4], Red, Hyperplane[#, cent] & /@ eigvec}}, ImageSize -> Small]]


(*using convexhullmesh *)
reg1 = ConvexHullMesh[pts3];
cent1 = RegionCentroid@reg1;
{eigval1, eigvec1} = Eigensystem@MomentOfInertia@reg1;

plt[reg1, eigvec1, cent1]
```

[image]

```
(*using convexhullregion*)
reg2 = ConvexHullRegion[pts3];
cent2 = RegionCentroid@reg2;
{eigval2, eigvec2} = Eigensystem@MomentOfInertia@reg2;

plt[Region@reg2, eigvec2, cent2]
```

[image]

Observe the orientation of the cutting planes; they look very different for the two cases. I think I can use `DiscretizeRegion@ConvexHullMesh[pts3]` to make the cutting planes in the first case to look like the latter. However, I am confused as to why `MomentOfInertia` is behaving differently in the two cases? **Is this a bug?**

Comment: MMA version 12.3.0 I get twice the same symmetric picture.

Comment: @DanielHuber I am using Mathematica 12.3.1 for Microsoft Window (64-Bit) (June 19,2021)

Comment: @DanielHuber sorry I corrected the `pts3`. They were missing precision. Can you kindly check now?

Comment: Now I get the same artefact. Looks like a bug to me  because the points are symmetrical. So there is no reason for asymmetries. Could you report this to support@wolfram.com?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann does Mathematica v12 have `ConvexHullRegion`? I thought it came in the later version

Comment: @DanielHuber I will add the bug tag to the question since it is not showing similar behaviour. thanks !

Comment: @UlrichNeumann maybe i did not understand. I am comparing why MomentOfInertia behaves differently on the outputs of ConvexHullRegion  vs ConvexHullMesh. I dont think you can run the second part of the code in v12.0

Comment: @AliHashmi Yes ConvexHullRegion was introduced with v12.2. I only recognized that Show[reg2] doesn't work, I changed it to Show[Region[reg2]] :

Comment: Interesting, `Max[Abs[MomentOfInertia[reg1] - MomentOfInertia[reg2]]]` is roughly `3.8*10^-17`. So the more noticeable discrepancy must come from `EigenSystem`?

Comment: It's not an artefact I think: The body has more than 3 symmtry axes, concerning the inertia that means complete rotational symmetry. Every pair of eigenvectors might be arbitrarily rotated!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann's answer seems like the correct one. But if you are looking for a more 'natural' looking eigen system, you can turn your almost regular extruded hexagon into a regular and exact hexagon through `RootApproximant[N[pts3]]`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not an artefact, Mathematica result is ok for both cases!

The hexagon plane (perpendicular to  `{0,0,1}` )  has six axes of symmetry. That means, concerning the inertia , the body is rotationally symmetrical!

```
J1 = MomentOfInertia@reg1;
{eigval1, eigvec1} = Eigensystem@J1;

J2 = MomentOfInertia@reg2;
{eigval2, eigvec2} = Eigensystem@J2;
```

The second and third eigenvalues are identical, which confirms mentioned rotational symmetry of the two regions

That's why rotation of the eigenvectors around `{0,0,1}` gives a new set of equivalent eigenvectors

```
rot1 = RotationMatrix[\[CurlyPhi], eigvec1[[1]]] // Chop; 
ev1rot = eigvec1 . rm // Chop; (* new eigenvectors*)
(J1 . Transpose[#] - Transpose[#] . DiagonalMatrix[eigval1]) &[ev1rot] // Chop; 
(*{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}*)
```

Same is true for `reg2`.

That's why the  different appearing eigenvectors `eigvec1, eigvec2` fullfill the eigensystem of both regions:

```
(J2 . Transpose[#] - Transpose[#] . DiagonalMatrix[eigval1]) &[eigvec1] // Chop
(*{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}*)

(J1 . Transpose[#] - Transpose[#] . DiagonalMatrix[eigval1]) &[eigvec2] // Chop
(*{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}*)
```

Comment: I understand your point. However, should not the eigensystem output the same result for convexhullmesh and convexhullregion, unless of course the two represent very different underlying objects?

Comment: I don't think so. `convexhullmesh`and `convexhullregion` don't know from each other. Both return a correct eigensystem, unfortunately the eigenvectors are different in this case

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to threshold values near zero in the inertia matrix.

```
principleVectors[reg_] := Eigensystem[Threshold[MomentOfInertia[reg]]]

Max[Abs[principleVectors[reg1] - principleVectors[reg2]]]
```

> ```
> 3.81639*10^-17
> ```

Comment: thanks. makes sense now. I think it is the small values of the off-diagonal entries that is making Eigensystem return different values. Btw, if you use `reg1 = DiscretizeRegion@ConvexHullMesh[pts3]` and `reg2 = DiscretizeRegion@BoundaryMeshRegion@ConvexHullRegion[pts3] ` the off-diagonal entries of the matrix are significantly large and therefore Eigensystem returns approx the same eigenvectors

Comment: upvoting your answer !